# Iterate list data type in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint

I found this interesting [SCSS advanced guide](https://gist.github.com/jareware/4738651#user-content-5-the-list-data-type), with lot of cool approaches to use. Then I got stucked on the one below, the iterator is clear but I cannot understand what the number `1` and number `2` are used for. Any ideas??

**SCSS**

```
$buttonConfig: 'save' 50px, 'cancel' 50px, 'help' 100px; 

@each $tuple in $buttonConfig {
  .button-#{nth($tuple, 1)} {
    width: nth($tuple, 2);
  }
}
```

**Compiled CSS**

```
.button-save {
  width: 50px;
}
.button-cancel {
  width: 50px;
}
.button-help {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: indexes 1-based of the <n>th tuple

Comment: OK, got it. Thx @fcalderan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth($list, $index)`: returns the value at $index position in $list
so in the last example , 
**$buttonConfig: 'save' 50px, 'cancel' 50px, 'help' 100px;** 
`$tuple` in first iteration will be 'save' 50 so ($tuple, 1) will be save and ($tuple, 2) will be the width value 50px and so on .

Comment: `:nth-child` isn’t involved anywhere here.